# Converting datasets to nested lists

Tags: dataset

Imagine the Shipments relation:

```
SP = Dataset[{
<|"SNO" -> "S1", "PNO" -> "P1", "QTY" -> 300|>,
<|"SNO" -> "S1", "PNO" -> "P2", "QTY" -> 200|>,
<|"SNO" -> "S1", "PNO" -> "P3", "QTY" -> 400|>,
<|"SNO" -> "S1", "PNO" -> "P4", "QTY" -> 200|>,
<|"SNO" -> "S1", "PNO" -> "P5", "QTY" -> 100|>,
<|"SNO" -> "S1", "PNO" -> "P6", "QTY" -> 100|>,
<|"SNO" -> "S2", "PNO" -> "P1", "QTY" -> 300|>,
<|"SNO" -> "S2", "PNO" -> "P2", "QTY" -> 400|>,
<|"SNO" -> "S3", "PNO" -> "P2", "QTY" -> 200|>,
<|"SNO" -> "S4", "PNO" -> "P2", "QTY" -> 200|>,
<|"SNO" -> "S4", "PNO" -> "P4", "QTY" -> 300|>,
<|"SNO" -> "S4", "PNO" -> "P5", "QTY" -> 400|>
}];
```

which is then Grouped By shipper (SNO):

```
grouped=SP[GroupBy[Key["SNO"]]]
```

What is a concise way to convert this into a List of Lists of Lists that contain only the Values?  (I suppose I am trying to reproduce Gather-like behavior with datasets.)

(Thanks Murta:)  I hope to see:

```
 {
 {{"P1",300},
  {"P2",200},
  {"P3",400},
  {"P4",200},
  {"P5",100}},
 {{"P1",300},
  {"P2",400}},
 {{"P2",200}},
 {{"P2",200},
  {"P4",300},
  {"P5",400}}
            }
```

Something like:

```
 {
 {"S1",{{"P1",300},
        {"P2",200},
        {"P3",400},
        {"P4",200},
        {"P5",100}}},
 {"S2",{{"P1",300},
        {"P2",400}}},
 {"S3",{{"P2",200}}},
 {"S4",{{"P2",200},
        {"P4",300},
        {"P5",400}}}
            }
```

might be even better!

Comment: Can you put the result that you want in your question?

Comment: I notice that you never Accepted an answer to this question.  Does something remain unanswered or unsatisfactory?  What can be done to improve the answers given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
Module[{grouped, keys},
  grouped = SP[GroupBy[Key["SNO"]]];
  keys = grouped[Keys] // Normal;
  {#, grouped[#][All, {"PNO", "QTY"}][All, Values] // Normal} & /@ keys]
```

> ```
> {{"S1", {{"P1", 300}, {"P2", 200}, {"P3", 400}, {"P4", 200}, {"P5", 100}, {"P6", 100}}}, 
>  {"S2", {{"P1", 300}, {"P2", 400}}}, 
>  {"S3", {{"P2", 200}}}, 
>  {"S4", {{"P2", 200}, {"P4", 300}, {"P5", 400}}}}
> ```

#### Edit

Perhaps a little better.

```
Module[{grouped, keys},
  grouped = SP[GroupBy[Key["SNO"]]];
  keys = grouped[Keys] // Normal;
  {#, grouped[#][All, {"PNO", "QTY"}] // Normal // Values} & /@ keys]
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is one option:

```
Normal@Values@SP[GroupBy[#, Key["SNO"], Values] &]
```

you get:

```
{{{"S1", "P1", 300}, {"S1", "P2", 200}, {"S1", "P3", 400}, {"S1", 
   "P4", 200}, {"S1", "P5", 100}, {"S1", "P6", 100}}, {{"S2", "P1", 
   300}, {"S2", "P2", 400}}, {{"S3", "P2", 200}}, {{"S4", "P2", 
   200}, {"S4", "P4", 300}, {"S4", "P5", 400}}}
```

or:

```
Normal@Normal@SP[GroupBy[#, Key["SNO"], Values] &]/. Rule -> List
```

for the second case:

```
{{"S1", {{"S1", "P1", 300}, {"S1", "P2", 200}, {"S1", "P3", 
    400}, {"S1", "P4", 200}, {"S1", "P5", 100}, {"S1", "P6", 
    100}}}, {"S2", {{"S2", "P1", 300}, {"S2", "P2", 
    400}}}, {"S3", {{"S3", "P2", 200}}}, {"S4", {{"S4", "P2", 
    200}, {"S4", "P4", 300}, {"S4", "P5", 400}}}}
```

You can also do it without Dataset:

```
ass = {<|"SNO" -> "S1", "PNO" -> "P1", "QTY" -> 300|>, <|
    "SNO" -> "S1", "PNO" -> "P2", "QTY" -> 200|>, <|"SNO" -> "S1", 
    "PNO" -> "P3", "QTY" -> 400|>, <|"SNO" -> "S1", "PNO" -> "P4", 
    "QTY" -> 200|>, <|"SNO" -> "S1", "PNO" -> "P5", "QTY" -> 100|>, <|
    "SNO" -> "S1", "PNO" -> "P6", "QTY" -> 100|>, <|"SNO" -> "S2", 
    "PNO" -> "P1", "QTY" -> 300|>, <|"SNO" -> "S2", "PNO" -> "P2", 
    "QTY" -> 400|>, <|"SNO" -> "S3", "PNO" -> "P2", "QTY" -> 200|>, <|
    "SNO" -> "S4", "PNO" -> "P2", "QTY" -> 200|>, <|"SNO" -> "S4", 
    "PNO" -> "P4", "QTY" -> 300|>, <|"SNO" -> "S4", "PNO" -> "P5", 
    "QTY" -> 400|>};
```

You get:

```
Normal@GroupBy[ass, Key["SNO"], Values] /. Rule -> List

{{"S1", {{"S1", "P1", 300}, {"S1", "P2", 200}, {"S1", "P3", 
    400}, {"S1", "P4", 200}, {"S1", "P5", 100}, {"S1", "P6", 
    100}}}, {"S2", {{"S2", "P1", 300}, {"S2", "P2", 
    400}}}, {"S3", {{"S3", "P2", 200}}}, {"S4", {{"S4", "P2", 
    200}, {"S4", "P4", 300}, {"S4", "P5", 400}}}}
```

Update for your last form:

```
Normal@Normal@SP[GroupBy[#, Key["SNO"], Values@#[[All,{"PNO","QTY"}]]&] &]/. Rule -> List

    {
 {"S1",{
         {"P1",300}
        ,{"P2",200}
        ,{"P3",400}
        ,{"P4",200}
        ,{"P5",100}
        ,{"P6",100}}
        }
,{"S2",{
         {"P1",300}
        ,{"P2",400}}
       }
,{"S3",{
        {"P2",200}}
        }
,{"S4",{
        {"P2",200}
        ,{"P4",300}
        ,{"P5",400}}
        }
}
```

Comment: There are very nice and clever.  Would it be possible to modify your answer so that the "SNO" (e.g. "S1") is not in the {"S1","P1",300} part?

Comment: For Association form you can use this: `Normal@GroupBy[ass, Key["SNO"], Values@*Query[All, {"PNO", "QTY"}]]/.Rule -> List`?

Comment: @EricBrown, see my answer using `KeyDrop`.

Comment: @Murta +1 you could use: `List @@@ Normal @ Normal @ SP[GroupBy[Key["SNO"] -> ({#PNO, #QTY} &)]]` to eliminate the "SNO" key.

Answer (score 3):

```
grouped = 
 SP[GroupBy[Key["SNO"]], KeyDrop["SNO"]][All, All, Values] // Normal //
   Normal // Column
```

Gives your second list if you don't mind the Rule at first Level:

```
S1->{{P1,300},{P2,200},{P3,400},{P4,200},{P5,100},{P6,100}}
S2->{{P1,300},{P2,400}}
S3->{{P2,200}}
S4->{{P2,200},{P4,300},{P5,400}}
```

Comment: +1 You could reduce the `SP[...][...]` expression to `SP[GroupBy[Key["SNO"]], KeyDrop["SNO"] /* Values]`.

Comment: @WReach, thanks, w/ practice am using composition more.

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
grouped = Normal[SP[GroupBy[Key["SNO"]], All, Rest][Values, Values]]
```